# How to install python on the hosgator cpanel

Tags: python, php, html, django, hosting

Hi guys someone knows how I can install python in hosgator, i have the Turbo plan but I do not see the option in cpanel to install it, because my project is on Django. Thanks
[image]

Comment: If you have SSH access to the server, cpanel isn't required.

Comment: I don't see `Turbo plan` on hosgator.com. What host is it - `shared`, `dedicated`, `VPS` ? For `shared` you may have to as hostgator's admins for this. Usually in `shared` hosts only admins may add new languages or other programs - for security reasons - because one computer/system is used by many people. You should also check

Comment: But when I check other shared plans on hosgator.com then I see it should have already installe Python and you don't have to install it. You may have to only read documentation on hosgator.com to see how to use it - see what modules it have already installed. Some hostings gives access to Python only to create simple scripts but not to run Django or Flask. Other need special methods to use Django (as Applications which automatically use `Gunicorn`)

Comment: I asked Google `hostgator django hosting` and I got [Django with Fastcgi](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/django-with-fastcgi)

Comment: Hey furas i see why you dont find my plan, its because i dont buy it on Hosgator.com y bought in Hosgator.mx, i think they are the same plans but in case i edit the question to add an image of the plan that I have, so you can see if with what I have I can install python or use my Django project